# Can you freeze a plastic mixer bowl?

Tags: freezing, stand-mixer

I made a chocolate crinkle cookie dough that needs to be frozen for 2 hours before forming and baking. Can I freeze it in the (Bosch) plastic mixer bowl or will that ruin the bowl?

Answer (score 7):

It won't ruin the bowl, but be careful handling it. [Plastic becomes more brittle when cold](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/why-do-plastics-get-brittle-when-they-get-cold/), and if you drop it, it may shatter or crack.